# How do I optimize this Javascript?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I tried to convert snippet 1 to snippet 2 but this did not work (the text fields did not clear).  f3aa and f3bb are each text fields that I need to clear after a sumbit.

Snippet 1

```
var target=document.getElementById('f3aa');
target.value='';
var target=document.getElementById('f3bb');
target.value='';
```

Snippet 2

```
o1('f3aa')=o1('f3bb')='';
```

Snippet 3

```
function  o1(a)
  {
  document.getElementById(a);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
X('f3aa').value = X('f3bb').value = '';
```

where `X` is your query-by-ID implementation.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/zmr29/

(I wrote a `X` function in my demo, but I assume that you either use a library or have some other shorthand for DOM queries.)

Comment: Can you verify/edit my answer.  I added in the minimization and the serial assignment.  Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Snippet 2 should be: `o1('f3aa').value = o1('f3bb').value = '';`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you were nearly there:

```
document.getElementById('f3aa').value = '';
document.getElementById('f3bb').value = '';
```

In your snippet 2, you are trying to assign an empty string to a DOM element, rather than the `value` property of that element.

In snippet 1, you assign a DOM element to the `target` variable, and then assign an empty string to the `value` property of the `target` variable. As `target` contains a DOM element, you assign that string to the `value` property of that element, which is equivalent to the code I have shown above.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to include the attribute names from your first snippet in your second:

```
document.getElementById('f3aa').value='';
document.getElementById('f3bb').value='';
```

(Note that this isn't really an "optimization" - there will be no noticeable difference in how quickly the two snippets run. Use whichever is more readable.)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's illegal to use `var` to declare a variable more than once in the same scope.

This code is bad:

```
var test = true;
var test = false;
```

This code is good:

```
var test = true;
    test = false; // <-- no "var" keyword here
```

Comment: The first example simply overwrites the first `test` value with the second. Your second example creates a global `test` variable that is shadowed by the local `test` (assuming we're in a function).

Comment: I love how you use indenting to trick people into thinking that the second line is part of the variable statement `:)`